# Как вывести многомерный массив на php

Tags: php, массивы

Добрый день.
Есть массив вида:

```
Array  
(  
    [0] => Array  
        (  
            [cat] => 1  
            [lawtitle] => Описание1  
            [filename] => 4.pdf  
        )  

    [1] => Array  
        (  
            [cat] => 1  
            [lawtitle] => Описание2  
            [filename] => 5.pdf  
        )  

)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно  вывести этого массива в таком виде:

Описание1

4.pdf

Описание2

5.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Просто

```
foreach ($array as $val) {
   echo $val['lawtitle'] . '<br/>'; // либо за место '<br/>' так PHP_EOL
   echo $val['filename'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    echo $val['lawtitle']. "<br>";
    echo $val['filename']. "<br>";

}
```

Comment: я раньше успел :D а вообще `$i` тут ненужен

Comment: Согласен, удалил :)